# Database that has easiest replication/automatic healing model

Tags: database

Hi I'm looking for database (any kind: RDBMS, NoSQL, NewSQL) that has a really simple replication model:

- I can write to any node, I can read that data from any node afterwards
- I can add a node and it would automatically copying some/full data to that node
- When a (from n) node is down (broken harddisk or hardware failure), there would be a copy of the data exists on another node

Is there such database exists?

Comment: You might consider mirror RAID disks, or frequent backups. Can you afford to lose a few minutes data, or none at all?